# make org-beamer-export-* to insert /framebreak before each top-level block

Tags: beamer, org-mode, export

I'm looking for an easy way to automatically insert `\framebreak` before each `block` - that is, for each sub-section of the org-file. e.g.

```
* Section 1
** Sub-Section 1.1
- a
- b
** Sub-Section 1.2
- c
- d
```

... should become:

```
\begin{frame}{Section 1}
\begin{block}{Sub-Section 1.1}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\framebreak

\begin{block}{Sub-Section 1.2}
\begin{itemize}
\item c
\item d
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}{\framebreak}`, but be warned, this will insert a `\framebreak` before every block.

Using this in org-mode is probably something like

```
#+latex_header: \BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}{\framebreak}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}{\framebreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Section 1}
\begin{block}{Sub-Section 1.1}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Sub-Section 1.2}
\begin{itemize}
\item c
\item d
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: good but it adds a first ugly slide (probably because there is a "block" inside the "maketitle" slide)...